# Windows 10 PC not getting full internet speed

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, internet-speed

My internet speed just got updated from 600Mbps to 800Mbps.  I bought a new modem to handle faster speeds, but I am still averaging between 400 and 600Mbps.  The cable guy came and checked the speed coming from the modem and from my ethernet switch and both are reading 1000Mbps.  It's definitely something specific to my PC.  I tried connecting a super old laptop to the same ethernet switch and it is reading 800+Mbps.  My link speed is 1000/1000 (Mbps).  I checked my network adapter drivers and they are all up-to-date.  I replaced all of the ethernet cables with brand new CAT8 cables.  What else could be causing this?

```
Motherboard: ASRock X370 Gaming K4
Network Adapter: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
             and Intel(R) l211 Gigabet Network Connection
```

**Update**

I ran windows in safe-mode with network connection and I am getting 900+Mbps which is even more than my expected speeds.

Comment: please add info about the PC and the network adapter in the question - perhaps the modem and switch too, but you seem to have ruled them out as an issue with the old laptop

Comment: Try running TCP/IP Reset and see if that makes any difference.   .........    Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: @JaromandaX, I'll edit the question and add that info.  Let me know if you want more.

Comment: @John, I tried those 3 things and still get the slower speeds.

Comment: If it is your machine that is the issue as the ISP says, it may be best to back up and rebuild it.

Comment: "Intel(R) l211 Gigabit Network Connection" - This is likely the problem, Intel network adapters suck, what driver version from Intel (not ASRock) do you have installed?

Comment: The Intel Driver version is: 12.18.11.1

Comment: My Intel NIC is fine.  Can your's be replaced?  Not easy, I think

Comment: I updated the question.  I was able to restart in safe mode and get the correct fast speeds.  But, I am unsure on how to narrow down the cause.

Comment: I checked in the Network column of the Task Manager while the speed test ran and only Chrome was taking up anything over 1Mbps and Chrome's speed was matching the speed test.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have exactly the same motherboard, and another with the same intel I211 NIC, and they both achieve expected speeds on my gigabit internet - so, the only difference being the driver version is 12.19.1.32 or 13.0.4.0

Comment: @JaromandaX, I did a scan with Intel's driver scanner and it says that I have the latest.